# No highlighting for replacement text using conceal

Tags: highlight, conceal

I just discovered Vim's [conceal](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27conceallevel%27) feature.

I've added the following to `~/.vim/after/syntax/haskell.vim`:

```
syntax match haskOperator "->" conceal cchar=→
syntax match haskOperator "<-" conceal cchar=←

highlight! link haskOperator Normal
```

And this to my vimrc:

```
setlocal conceallevel=2
```

This works and replaces `->` with `→` and `<-` with `←`:

[image: concealed characters, with highlights]

That's nice but I feel that the replacement arrows are visually too prominent: I want to get rid of their highlighting, the grey background.

I tried to use [`transparent`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#:syn-transparent), but this makes the arrows entirely invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The looks of those replacement characters are defined by the `Conceal` [highlight group](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups).

Adding this to my vimrc makes any text highlighted with that group use my terminal emulator's default foreground and background:

```
highlight Conceal ctermbg=none ctermfg=none guibg=none guifg=none
```

In effect, the replacement text is not highlighted anymore:

[image: concealed text, no highlight]